# C++ templates: prevent instantiation of base template

Tags: c++, templates

I have an interface

```
std::string
get_string(Source const &s, std::string const &d);
int
get_int(Source const &s, int const &d);
bool
get_bool(Source const &s, bool const &d);
```

which I'd like to change to

```
template<class T>
T
get(Source const &s, T const &d);
```

But *there's no sensible base template*, so the actual base definition is a legal but useless (`return d;`).  What can I do to force compile-time failure if the base is instantiated?  Is there an idiomatic solution for this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by *base template*? Also remember that function templates don't specialize, but overload.

Comment: "base template" as opposed to a "specialization"

Comment: If you don't want to define a "base template" anyway, there is no point in adding templates into the mix. Your initial thought of providing overloads for the various types is correct.

Comment: @Terry Mahaffey: I dunno.  This is straightforward compile-time polymorphism, my question is about compile-time pure virtual methods. Would you say that purely virtual methods in runtime polymorphism are pointless?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't define the template, just declare it and define the three specializations.

```
template <typename T>
T get(Source const &, T const &);

template<>
std::string get(Source const &s, std::string const &d) {
    return d + s.stringval(); // or whatever
}
```

[Edit: removed stuff about overloads - just for once, template function specialization does actually seem to be better. Who woulda thunk?]

Comment: implicit conversions are the reason to go for a template

Comment: Do you mean the caller is expected always to specify the type, rather than ever allowing it to be inferred from the parameters?

Comment: I mean that I want the selected function to exactly match actual types

Comment: ... and no conversions on the values passed to the selected function

Comment: Oh, I get it. For example if you define it with overloads and call `get(Source(), "hello")`, you get the bool version of the function, which probably isn't what you wanted. If you define it with templates and do the same, you get an error because there's no template instantiation for that char array type.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: exactly.  thank you for the excellent answer BTW: no ugly hack, fails with a clear error message (not before link time though, which is a small minus; oh well).

Answer (score 3):

just do

```
string get(source, string);
int get (source, int);
bool get(source, bool);
```

Comment: that opens a can of worms since `bool` and `int` are implicitly convertible back and forth.

Comment: It'll be fine, the compiler won't implicitly convert them when the correct unconverted overload is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay for run-time polymorphism, you can do this...

```
template <typename T>
class Interface
{
   virtual T get(Source const &s, T const &d) = 0;
};

class StringInterface : public Interface<std::string>
{
   virtual std::string get(Source const& s, std::string const& d);
};

// etc.
```

Since your base is an abstract class, you will get a compile-time failure if you try to instantiate it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Declare the baseclass (t) as abstract, that way an instance can never be created of that class.

Comment: the question is about free functions, not classes