# Specializations only for C++ template function with enum non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, enums, template-specialization, static-assert

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155491/hide-function-template-declare-specializations) except that rather than dealing with typename template parameters, I am trying to use an enum non-type template parameter.

Is it possible to have a templated (class member function) with only specializations, no general (working) definition in the case of non-type template parameter?

1. I was able to get one version working, by declaration in the class body and providing specializations only, but any misuse calling with a non-defined template parameter doesn't produce an error until linking. What's worse is the missing symbol cryptically refers to the enum's integral value and not its name, so it would be confusing to other developers.
2. I was able to get the `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` technique from the referenced question to work for typename template parameter only.

This code demonstrates the idea.  I don't want the `CAT`-version call to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

// CLASS HEADER FILE:
struct foo_class
{
    enum AllowedTypes { DOG, CAT };

    template <AllowedTypes type>
    void add_one_third( double bar ) const
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(sizeof(type)==0, "enum type not supported.");
    }
};

// CLASS SOURCE FILE
template<>
void foo_class::add_one_third<foo_class::DOG>( double bar ) const
{
    std::cout << "DOG specialization: " << bar + 1./3. << std::endl;
}


// USER SOURCE FILE
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Template Specialization!\n\n";

    foo_class a;
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::DOG>(3.0); // should succeed
    // Compilation fails with or without the following line:
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::CAT>(3.0); // should fail at compile-time

    return 0;
}
```

**Background:**
I have a class member function that takes an enum "ArgType" and a name.

```
void declareKernelArgument( ArgType type, std::string name );
```

The definition has turned into an `if..else..if..else` list for the half-dozen or so allowed ArgType cases. I also have to have final case that throws an exception for an not-allowed ArgType. I'm thinking it would be cleaner to move ArgType to a template parameter, and provide a specialization for each allowed ArgType.  Misuse would be caught at compile-time.

Comment: Why do you prefer enum tagging instead of the type itself, or type-based tagging?

Comment: my example choice of `T_INT` and `T_DOUBLE` were bad bad names I now realize.  I'll change it to something less confused with a real type as that is my actual use interest.

Comment: the idea is to be able to comment out the second call of add_one_third and compilation should succeed.  It does not.

Answer (score 7):

**With partial specialization of a structure inside the class:**

```
#include <iostream>

class foo_class
{
    public:
    enum AllowedTypes { T_DOUBLE, T_INT };

    private:
    template <AllowedTypes type, typename T>
    struct AddOneThird;

    template <typename T>
    struct AddOneThird<T_DOUBLE, T> {
        static void apply(T bar) {
            std::cout << "T_DOUBLE specialization: " << bar + 1.0/3.0 << std::endl;
        }
    };

    public:
    template <AllowedTypes type>
    void add_one_third( double bar ) const {
        AddOneThird<type, double>::apply(bar);
    }
};

int main() {
    foo_class a;
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_DOUBLE>(3.0);
    // error: incomplete type ‘foo_class::AddOneThird<(foo_class::AllowedTypes)1u
    // a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_INT>(3.0); // should fail at compile-time

    return 0;
}
```

**With full specialization of a (friend) class:**

```
#include <iostream>

class foo_class
{
    public:
    enum AllowedTypes { T_DOUBLE, T_INT };

    // if needed
    // template<AllowedTypes> friend struct AddOneThird;

    public:
    template <AllowedTypes type> void add_one_third( double bar ) const;
};

template <foo_class::AllowedTypes>
struct AddOneThird;

template <>
struct AddOneThird<foo_class::T_DOUBLE> {
    static void apply(double bar) {
        std::cout << "T_DOUBLE specialization: " << bar + 1.0/3.0 << std::endl;
    }
};

template <foo_class::AllowedTypes type>
void foo_class::add_one_third( double bar) const {
    AddOneThird<type>::apply(bar);
}


int main() {
    foo_class a;
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_DOUBLE>(3.0);
    // error: incomplete type ‘AddOneThird<(foo_class::AllowedTypes)1u>’ used
    //        in nested name specifier
    //a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_INT>(3.0); // should fail at compile-time

    return 0;
}
```

**Utilizing C++11 or boost::enable_if:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class foo_class
{
    public:
    enum AllowedTypes { T_DOUBLE, T_INT };

    template <AllowedTypes type>
    typename std::enable_if<type == T_DOUBLE>::type
    add_one_third( double bar ) const {
        std::cout << "T_DOUBLE specialization: " << bar + 1.0/3.0 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo_class a;
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_DOUBLE>(3.0);
    // error: no matching function for call to ‘foo_class::add_one_third(double)’
    //a.add_one_third<foo_class::T_INT>(3.0); // should fail at compile-time
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising.  Why does the call which should fail, result in the compiler error `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'foo_class::AddOneThird<1, double>'`, when I would think it would lead to the same linking missing definition case I was able to get to?

Comment: @NoahR It's similar to a forward declaration of a class: It gives a compile time error if the forward declared class is used.

Comment: I'm not able to get this idea working for a more realistic use case: main() in one source file, foo_class declared in a header file, and apply() defined in a separate cpp source file.  Can you remove the `typename T` template parameter?  It is not necessary for my question and is confusing the issue.

Comment: @NoahR It is not allowed to fully specialize a nested class, hence the `typename T`

Comment: ok, I was able to move the definition of `apply()` to a separate C++ source file. Is it possible to pull the partial specialization for `struct AddOneThird<T_DOUBLE,T>` out of the header as well?  It adds a lot of noise to the header file that is only related to implementation.

Comment: considering that some more, even if it was possible, that would surely put us back in the situation where the use error is not revealed until linking.

Answer (score 1):

[From Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

> It's a lot less intuitive to specialize function templates. For one thing, you can't partially specialize them -- pretty much just because the language says you can't.[2] For another thing, function template specializations don't overload. This means that any specializations you write will not affect which template gets used, which runs counter to what most people would intuitively expect. After all, if you had written a nontemplate function with the identical signature instead of a function template specialization, the nontemplate function would always be selected because it's always considered to be a better match than a template.
>
> If you're writing a function template, prefer to write it as a single function template that should never be specialized or overloaded, and implement the function template entirely in terms of a class template. This is the proverbial level of indirection that steers you well clear of the limitations and dark corners of function templates. This way, programmers using your template will be able to partially specialize and explicitly specialize the class template to their heart's content without affecting the expected operation of the function template. This avoids both the limitation that function templates can't be partially specialized, and the sometimes surprising effect that function template specializations don't overload. Problem solved.

Your enum type sizeof is not 0, change that to 4 at least. Otherwise this will not work. A enum element size is not 0.

Without that everything runs

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo_class
{
    enum AllowedTypes { DOG, CAT };

    template <AllowedTypes type>
    void add_one_third( double bar ) const
    {
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
void foo_class::add_one_third<foo_class::DOG>( double bar ) const
{
    std::cout << "DOG specialization: " << bar + 1./3. << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Template Specialization!\n\n";

    foo_class a;
    a.add_one_third<foo_class::DOG>(3.0); // should succeed
    // Compilation fails with or without the following line:
    //a.add_one_third<foo_class::CAT>(3.0); // should fail at compile-time

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the idea is to be able to comment out the second call of add_one_third and compilation should succeed.  It does not.

Comment: check your boost static assert. and please post your compiler output

Comment: yes, a possible problem spot, but I don't know how else to make the assertion.  But more likely, (with the CAT line disabled), the static assert should not even be made, yet it is.

Comment: right.  But uncomment your CAT line.  This compiles and runs and outputs "YES".  The desired behavior is that it does not compile as CAT is not an allowed case.

Comment: it seems that I was wrong and template specialization does add methods on the fly, i'm sorry. I am searching the standard for an explanation on this and will come back to you later. On the meanwhile, check this [amazing article on the subject by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the enum case and the referenced question using a typename parameter is that the default definition will be compiled for any use.  So, a working solution is as simple as modifying the `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` condition to check allowed enum values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

// CLASS HEADER FILE:
struct foo_class
{
    enum AllowedTypes { DOG, CAT, MOUSE };

    template <AllowedTypes type>
    void give_bath() const
    {
        // compile fails if ever attempting to use this function with CAT parameter.
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( (type==DOG) || (type==MOUSE) , "enum type not supported.");
        throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected. Above list inconsistent with specializations.");   
    }
};

// CLASS SOURCE FILE
template<>
void foo_class::give_bath<foo_class::DOG>() const
{
    std::cout << "DOG is bathed." << std::endl;
}

template<>
void foo_class::give_bath<foo_class::MOUSE>() const
{
    std::cout << "MOUSE is bathed." << std::endl;
}


// USER SOURCE FILE
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Template Specialization!\n\n";

    foo_class a;
    a.give_bath<foo_class::DOG>(); //success
    a.give_bath<foo_class::MOUSE>(); // success
    // Compilation fails with the following line:
    //a.give_bath<foo_class::CAT>(); // fails at compile-time as intended.

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the whole design smells bad and could likely be handled more elegantly with AllowedTypes being a `struct`/`class` with inherited specializations.  But this gets to the question at hand.