# c++ Using a a template function with enum class and overloaded conversion operators

Tags: c++, member-functions, function-templates, enum-class, conversion-operator

I was reading the sample code on another post [Specializations only for C++ template function with enum non-type template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721201/specializations-only-for-c-template-function-with-enum-non-type-template-param)

and I'm trying to take it one step further, by using a overloaded conversion operator to use the object as if it was its enum member to call a template function.

```
//in my .h
enum class AllowedTypes { Cat, Dog };

class A {
AllowedTypes animal;

public:
//constructor
A(AllowedTypes t): animal(t) {};
explicit operator AllowedTypes*() const { return (AllowedTypes*) animal; }
operator AllowedTypes() const { return animal; }
template <AllowedTypes type>
void ability() const;
}

//second class
struct B{
//tempalte function
template <AllowedTypes type>
void ability() const;
}

//in my cpp
template<>
void B::ability<AllowedTypes::Dog>() const
{
std::cout << "Dog ability." << std::endl;
}
template<>
void B::ability<AllowedTypes::Cat>() const
{
std::cout << "Cat ability." << std::endl;
}


//in my main
Class* a = new A(AllowedType(1))
Class* b = new B();

//this calls work!
b->ability<AllowedTypes::Cat>(); 

//trying to get the type and calling ability via conversion doesn't
AllowedTypes type = (AllowedTypes)*a; // this converts correctly!
b->ability<type>(); //does not call correctly
```

this last line doesn't work, I'm trying to put my converted object in the template and call the ability specific to the type that A has. I've tried a few different things but can't seem to find what I'm looking for, is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: `explicit operator AllowedTypes*() const { return (AllowedTypes*) animal; }` !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to set a template type parameter using a runtime value rather than compile time value.

```
Class* a = new A(AllowedType(1)) // The call to new here makes 'type' below a runtime value

b->ability<AllowedTypes::Cat>(); // AllowedTypes::Cat can be supplied at compile time

AllowedTypes type = (AllowedTypes)*a; // this converts correctly!
b->ability<type>(); //does not call correctly
```

Here is your code running [online](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdf6dab909539dc0) which points to the exact problem. Next time your confused about why your template type isnt getting deduced correctly/throwing an error use `constexpr` to figure out why.

And here is an answer explaining why `new` results in an ill-formed `constexpr`: [C++14: can you call new in a constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897015/c14-can-you-call-new-in-a-constexpr)